# How can I set the date to the jDateChooser which is retrieved from the database?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-7, jdatechooser

I have a form on which I want to access a date from the database and show in jDateChooser for a particular record.

I saved the date as a string in the database.

How do I get the date from the database table and how do I set that date in jDateChooser?

Comment: Please take the time to read through the "JDBC Database Access" trail (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html).  Which JDateChooser are you using?  What format is the date value in, in the database?  (Why did you store it as String?)

Comment: I was getting exception while I was saving date using 'Date' data type.I am using Jcalendars JdateChooser.Date is in dd-MM-YYYY format.

Comment: I have date stored in DB as 2014-09-20 format.. it is not getting/parsing a proper date value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you stored the date in the database as `String` then you're going to need to retrieve it as `String`

```
String dateValue = resultset.getString(...); // What ever column
java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(dateValue);

jDateChooser.setDate(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `date chooser` that you've mentioned is this one http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/658/jdatechooser-1-2 then one possible solution might be this.

```
String dateValue = resultset.getString(2); // Your column Name
java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(dateValue);

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
jDateChooserDCC.setSelectedDate(cal);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date dateValue = null;
try {
    dateValue = date.parse(resultset.getstring(1));
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(pegawai.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
jdateChooser.setDate(dateValue);
```

note : resultset.getstring(1) is data from database mysql